# Parsing JSON from MySQL table field to GridDB as Collection

Tags: griddb

I have a MySQL table field with JSON content inside. I tried searching the net around but couldn't find a way how to store JSON from MySQL to GridDB as key value pair.

My sample data are such:

```
{
"productName": "HP Desktop",
"price": 2000,
"specification": [],
}
```

I expect it to store in GridDB as a collection with `productName` as the RowKey.

Comment: Just to nail down what your question is really about: 1) Do you have a problem extracting the json data from mysql in a specific format and thus you have a mysql question how to transform data to a specific structure? 2) Or the way you extract data from mysql is fine, but you have a griddb question on transforming that dataset in griddb? Deciding between the two questions help us to determine if your question is about one or the other database product.

Comment: Maybe what you want! `JSON_DECODE()` will convert a json string representing an array of key-value pairs into an array of key-value pairs

Comment: @Shadow i have no issue on extracting the JSON from mysql, my problem is i don't know how to assign the key value pair into GridDB as a collection